# Is kimchi a suitable addition to a noodle soup?

Tags: soup, kimchi

I have just returned from having purchased a can of kimchi. I have no idea what the contents are, since they are written in Korean, but thought that mixing it into the broth at the last minute might increase the soup's flavour.

Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: "I have no idea what the contents are" - are you trying to ask what kimchi is?

Comment: I am presuming that the main ingredient is fermented cabbage, I am unaware what else, if anythihg, is considered "standard" for kimchi.

Comment: Depends on what kind of noodles you use and what else is in the soup.  Some soups taste very good with kimchi or sauerkraut.  You can cook your soup without kimchi and then add some to the first plate.

Comment: @Doug - while cabbage is the standard, generic "kimchee," there is daikon radish kimchee, a more mild version of cabbage kimchee, cucumber, green onion, chive, etc etc etc.  A lot of variation if you happen to go to a Korean-specific store and look at their offerings. For the "standard" usually salt, scallion and/or chives, garlic, hot pepper, shredded daikon, sometimes tiny salted shrimps or fish sauce for other standard ingredients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kimchi are not preferred to be added directly to soup. Usually you would fry the Kimchi (ideally in Sesame oil) to slightly transparent or having minor brown on the edges, before adding into the soup, and boil for . That is not only applicable to [KimChi JiGae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimchi_jjigae)- but also other varieties of KimChi broth (e.g. hotpot, Kimchi ramen/noodles (BuDae JiGae) etc.)

Adding Kimchi directly to soup/broth and boil is more a Northern Chinese way of cooking (where Kimchi is not called kimchi but literally called "Spicy Pickled Cabbage").

Frying beforehand and adding directly to soup/water can taste very, very different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's almost a required element for me any time I'm eating the standard cheap ramen or noodle bowls.  I usually add it at the end so I don't cook all the crunch out of the kimchee.

I often take five or six frozen gyoza/dumplings, add them to the small pot of water, bring that to a boil, then add the ramen noodles, then, after the noodle cooking time, add *some* of that salty seasoning packet and the kimchee.

As pointed out in the selected answer, cooking it, as a step for soups and stews is also very standard, but I'd disagree about it not also being a fine addition, as is, to a noodle soup.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. Heres a recipe you could try http://norecipes.com/blog/kimchi-jigae-recipe-kimchi-soup/

Answer (score 1):

Absent any information (not even a picture?) I'd assume it's the common variety with the dominant seasoning being spicy red chili. It's certainly a reasonable thing to put in a soup: kimchi soup and kimchi stew are popular dishes. It's also a very common standard side dish. If you're unsure, just open the can, taste it, and see what you think you'll like best.